# Monitoring with JBOSS 7.1 JMX in ZABBIX agent windows

Tags: windows, jboss, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have a problem when i try connect my zabbix server with JBoss 7.1, the error is:

**Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.**

I think the fault is in the client configuration, the agent run in windows, some know what command I need to use for change the port in run.conf.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to note that in order to monitor JBoss through JMX you do not need to have Zabbix agent running. Instead, you should run [Zabbix Java gateway](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/concepts/java) (see also [section on JMX monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring)).

However, as of Zabbix 2.2.5, the gateway only supports JMX service URLs of the following type:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://{CONN}:{PORT}/jmxrmi
```

whereas JBoss seems to be monitored using URLs of type

```
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://{CONN}:{PORT}
```

Consequently, JBoss monitoring with Zabbix is currently not possible out of the box, but you can use patches and ideas described in [ZBXNEXT-1274](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274).